# is there a way to make PHP variable in another <?php ?> scope

Tags: php

I'm trying to use variable I have in `<?php ?>` in another `<?php ?>`

for example,

```
   <?php 
      $helloWorld = "Hello World";
    ?>

    ... some HTML

        <?php 
       function echoHello(){
           echo $helloWorld;
       }
    ?>
```

The variable is not variable in the second part. How to make the variable visible so I can access later when I want to execute some PHP script.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: It should be visible: http://ideone.com/ZLy2yt.

Comment: PHP mode `<?php ?>` has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: I know that, But for some reason it dosen't work in PHPCake ctp file.

Comment: Why don't use echo "Hello World"; in your second scope?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It should be visible? Not if you'd properly copied the code posted by the OP.....

Comment: @dbf: I did copy-and-paste, but it looks like the question has been edited since then!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So it seems, sry m8 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be visible, assuming you're still on the same pageload, one or other of them is not inside a function, and many other factors that can only be evaluated by seeing your full code.

But just a quick guess, have you tried View Source? If the browser shows your raw PHP code inside the source, then the server is not parsing the PHP at all and it's just silently hiding as invalid HTML tags.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in CakePHP ctp file. For some reason I can't do it. I get error Undefined variable.

Comment: the variable is inside a function. how can I access global variable.

Comment: Either pass it as a parameter, or use the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you echo the variable in the  section of the page it won't show. 

And you need to call the function to run it, so underneath put **echoHello();**

If both  are on the same page, it should work just fine